# Change default download folder when working remotely in VSCode in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-code

When working remotely via SSH or WSL in VSCode in MS Windows, I can right-click a file in the Explorer view and choose "Download", this will download the file to the local computer. But the default download folder is always `C:\Users\$USERNAME\.ssh`, which doesn't make sense for me. I can't find any settings related to this.

How can I change the default download folder in VSCode when working remotely via SSH or WSL?